# How to create dynamic forms on the fly based on models in mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

We have some customers who want to use web pages differently. If I should be more clear about this, suppose we have a Person model and this model obviously has some properties like Name, Number, Address etc.

Customer X wants the property **Name** as *required*, **Number** as *invisible* and **Address** as *readonly*

Customer Y wants the property **Name** as *required*, **Number** as *required* and **Address** as *invisible*.

Other customers want these pages differently.

I don't want to create one page per customer. So as I can see, I might need something like a dynamic web page builder on the fly that would provide our customers to build custom pages based on the model.

How do you think I can handle this? Is there an open-source solution in MVC or jQuery, perhaps? Any other recommendation?

Comment: the use case might be somewhat analogous to form-builder or questionnaire-builder software, of which there are quite a few examples around online, some commercial some not. I'm not going to do all your research for you, but you might be able to find something that's either compatible with MVC, or has its own model and validation structure built in (meaning you don't need the Model part of MVC so much).

Comment: @ADyson I have had a quick look before asking here, however any solution that I found wasn't based on the mvc model. All creating from its own model or a front-end side solution. I'd be appreciated if you know one.

Comment: How many customers do you have? Having a master layout page for your customers and then individual customized views per customer is a perfectly acceptable approach.. unless of course you have lots of different customers ALL with different requirements.

Comment: Anything I've used before like this was completely custom and built in-house, so I can't give you a recommendation of something out there in the wild. In any case, direct recommendations are considered off-topic on SO, partly because you tend to get opinions and marketing spam, and partly because the purpose of the site is a Q&A for specific programming problems, not a research hub.

Comment: What do you mean by `MVC Model`? To me, it is just some classes defining some properties and eventually, some attributes to improve validation or stuff like that. You want to know if there is some attributes in the framework that can help you out of the box?

Comment: @Wheels73 Lots of customers that is not possible to create a layout page for all. Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: @hhk - I'd go with a data driven solution then. Create perhaps an XML config stored in the database. You can then create meta data regarding what controls to create and whether they're visible or read only.

Comment: instead of using strongly typed use here you can use a client side html form and with the help of jquery you can achieve the required validation by just removing attr required as per condition ...just pass the data as json object to your server and you are good to go

Comment: @RAHULSR that's a good start but there would still need to be a server-side validation as well to ensure the integrity of the data, which is more awkward in a strongly-typed language like C# (in PHP, this would actually be quite easy to do with a database backend to store the customer configs). You can't trust that some malicious user or bot has not bypassed or altered the javascript validation.

Comment: you can do all the back end data integrity checking like anti forgery tocken or to modal state validation just add @antiforgerytoken inside the form and in server side it will be checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is our solution:

We created one model class to store settings in database, named as *CustomModelEditor*. Also we created a public class for creating our own `@Html` method on the Razor view side, and named it as *CustomWebForm*.

In *CustomWebForm* class we created a method returning an `MvcHtmlString` value and we overrode html inputs with `InputExtensions`. See code below.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString MyTextBox(this HtmlHelper html, CustomModelEditor property, object additionalViewData = null)
        {

            dynamic htmlattr = additionalViewData ?? new ExpandoObject();

            htmlattr.@class = "form-control";
            htmlattr.type = property.InputType.ToString().ToLower();

            if (property.IsRequired)
                htmlattr.required = "required";
            if (property.IsReadonly)
                htmlattr.@readonly = "readonly";
            if (property.IsDisabled)
                htmlattr.disabled = "disabled";
            if (property.Length != 0)
                htmlattr.maxlength = property.Length;
            if (property.Value == null)
                property.Value = property.DefaultValue;

            htmlattr.value = property.Value;

            return InputExtensions.TextBox(html, property.Name, property.Value, htmlattr);
        }
```

I had this for Labels, CheckBoxes and other html elements.

On the Controller we created an `ExpandoObject`, in order to pass input settings from database.

```
    public ActionResult Test()
    {

        dynamic contact = new ExpandoObject();

        // this part is static for now, will be get input settings from database
        contact.Name = new CustomModelEditor();
        contact.Name.Value = null;
        contact.Name.Name = nameof(contact.Name);
        contact.Name.DefaultValue = "Not Set";
        contact.Name.IsRequired = true;

        contact.Email = new CustomModelEditor();
        contact.Email.Name = nameof(contact.Email);
        contact.Email.Value = "";
        contact.Email.InputType = DataModels.InputType.Email;
        contact.Email.DefaultValue = "";
        contact.Email.IsRequired = true;

        return View(contact);
    }
```

On the Razor side in view.cshtml, I just called *MyTextBox* method.

```
@using MyWebProject.DataModels
@using System.Dynamic

@model dynamic

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<form>

    @Html.MyTextBox((CustomModelEditor)Model.Name)
    @Html.MyTextBox((CustomModelEditor)Model.Email)
    <button type="submit">test</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a CustomerValidation Entity per customer and store all the validations in DB for each customer.
in Your API you can create a service to check for validations and Return the Model with errors if any validations fail based on customer template.

```
public class CustomerValidation
{
   public string propertyName {get;set;}
   public string validationRegex {get;set;}
   public string ValidationMessage {get;set;}
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public int CustomerId {get;set;}
   public virtual Customer CustomerInfo {get;set;}
}
```

sample entry for CustomerValidation can be

```
Name, ^[a-zA-Z ]*$ ,Name should start with letter
```

Comment: i think op didnt said anything about validation

Comment: @Usman validation is also a case. However I am looking for a solution that makes the customer create the form from properties. But thanks Nitin, I will need this at the end of day.

Comment: @hhk you can also use this Entity to Create a Form and insert Fields Visible entry in CustomerValidation or you can rename this Entity to CustomerDynamicFieldsAttributes , while developing a View you can check for any fields if that field need to be displayed or needs to be required.